# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" when Generating allure report

Tags: java, jenkins, allure

**I am getting error**

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*

When jenkins triggers allure.bat file for generating the report.

I know this issue is related to heap size and also tried to increase the size but still getting same error.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to modify the below setting in `allure.bat` if it is Windows system else in allure as it is a shell script.

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx1G
```

In my case the above parameter is empty. After making above changes my problem got solved and able to generate reports.

Comment: Same works in the Linux too, we were facing it recently and adding this env variable at stage level helped to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the report logic you can only keep increasing the heap to find what is the sufficient size to run it. After determining the minimum working heap size you should make the call. If the increased memory consumption is acceptable, leave it be. Otherwise tweak the report configuration.